# HQL order by for two different fileds

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I want to select data from Workflow table using order by.How to do so?

```
public Workflow getDocById(String id) {
    Query queryWfManager = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Workflow where id =:id");
    queryWfManager.setParameter("id", id);

    Workflow wfManagerList = (Workflow) queryWfManager.list();
    Query queryWfDetails = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from WorkflowDetails where workflowCode =:workflowCode order by wfBlockId order by stepSeq");
    queryWfDetails.setParameter("workflowCode", wfManagerList.getWorkflowCode());

    List<WorkflowDetails> queryWfDetailList = queryWfDetails.list();
    wfManagerList.setSteps(queryWfDetailList);
    return wfManagerList;
}
```

Which One is correct Writing oreder by order by wfBlockId , stepSeq OR  order by wfBlockId order by stepSeq?

```
public Workflow getDocById(String id) {
    Query queryWfManager = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Workflow where id =:id");
    queryWfManager.setParameter("id", id);

    Workflow wfManagerList = (Workflow) queryWfManager.list();
    Query queryWfDetails = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from WorkflowDetails where workflowCode =:workflowCode order by wfBlockId , stepSeq");
    queryWfDetails.setParameter("workflowCode", wfManagerList.getWorkflowCode());

    List<WorkflowDetails> queryWfDetailList = queryWfDetails.list();
    wfManagerList.setSteps(queryWfDetailList);
    return wfManagerList;
}
```

Comment: order by wfBlockId , stepSeq is correct

Comment: Your first option is invalid because of the error in the SQL order by clause

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Query queryWfDetails = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession()
    .createQuery("FROM WorkflowDetails where workflowCode =:workflowCode ORDER BY wfBlockId , stepSeq");
```

The above query is correct.